# When does initialize check for object validity?

Tags: r, r-s4

From Chambers' (excellent) *[Extending R (2016)](https://www.crcpress.com/Extending-R/Chambers/p/book/9781498775717)*:

> A validity method will be called automatically from the default method for initialize(). The recommended form of an initialize method ends with a callNextMethod() call, to ensure that subclass slots can be specified in a call to the generator for the class. If this convention is followed, initialization will end with a call to the default method, and the validity method will be called after all initialization has occurred.

I thought I understood, but the behavior I am getting does not seem to follow this convention.

```
setClass("A", slots = c(s1 = "numeric"))

setValidity("A", function(object) {
  if (length(object@s1) > 5) {
    return("s1 longer than 5")
  }
  TRUE
})

setMethod("initialize", "A", function(.Object, s1, ...) {
  if (!missing(s1)) .Object@s1 <- s1 + 4
  callNextMethod(.Object, ...)
})

A <- new("A", rep(1.0, 6))
A
# An object of class "A"
# Slot "s1":
#   [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5
validObject(A)
# Error in validObject(A) : invalid class “A” object: s1 longer than 5
```

I expected the validity checking to be done by adding `callNextMethod()` to the end of the initialize method. Adding an explicit `validObject(.Object)` before `callNextMethod()` works, but I am clearly not understanding something here.

Obviously, I can also do all the same checks in the validity method, but ideally all of the validity checking would occur within `setValidity` so future edits live in one place.

Changing the `initialize` function slightly gives the desired result -- is there a reason to use one approach over the other? Chambers seems to prefer using `.Object@<-` whereas I have seen the following method elsewhere (Gentlemman & Hadley).

```
setMethod("initialize", "A", function(.Object, s1, ...) {
  if (!missing(s1)) s1 + 4
  else s1 <- numeric()
  callNextMethod(.Object, s1 = s1, ...)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best guide comes from `initialize` itself — if you inspect the code for the default method

```
getMethod("initialize",signature(.Object="ANY"))
```

then you see that it does indeed contain an explicit call to `validObject` at the end:

```
...
    validObject(.Object)
  }
  .Object
}
```

so if you define your own `initialize` method, the most similar thing you could do would be to call it at the end of your method, right before you call `callNextMethod`.

In your case, when you call `callNextMethod`, that is only checking that the slot you have created is a valid `numeric` object (which it is), rather than checking the validity of the larger object (which requires the `s1` slot to be no longer than 5 elements)

Comment: **This approach would be bad practice**, because then the method would not allow for extending the class to subclasses. My point is that the default method should be called, and the object should be checked -- I don't understand why it's not.

Comment: You need to end the custom `initialize` with `callNextMethod` -- and the (hypothetical) problem with explicitly checking the object before calling `callNextMethod` is "some modifications are likely to require objects that are temporarily invalid." (Chambers, *Extending R*)

Comment: Sure, but your question asked when `initialize` checked for validity. Have made it clearer why your case isn't behaving the way you might have thought.